# Как можно реализовать чтение числа из файла?

Tags: c, файлы, числа

Есть файл с числами. В нем последовательность из чисел. Например, 97 , 98 и 97, 99, 256 ... записанных подряд, то есть так:

```
97989799256...
```

Все числа имеют тип `int`, они были записаны в файл с помощью функции `fprintf(file, "%d", число);`

Можно ли корректно прочесть их в буфер не добавляя разделительные знаки между числами? Возможно, читать из файла по 4 байта? Какие функции для этого подошли бы? Я пробую прочесть одно число через `fread`и вывести его на экран, но почему-то программа вылетает. Вот мой код:

```
FILE* outFile;
outFile = fopen (outputFileName, "w");

FILE* inFile; 
inFile = fopen (inputFileName, "rb");

while (feof(inFile)!=0){
    int * buffer = checkNull(malloc(1*sizeof(int)));
    fread (buffer, 4, 1, inFile);
    printf("%d", buffer);
}

fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);
```

У меня был текстовый файл со строкой `abacabadabacabae` [из примера][1] на первом шаге кодирования я прочел из файла букву `а`, которая была в словаре, затем `b` последовательность символов `ab` занес в словарь с кодом `256`, а код символа `а` (97) занес в файл с числами. Далее к `b` конкатенировал `a`, занес `ba` в словарь с кодом 257, а `b` (98) в файл с числами. Теперь когда я встречу в файле числа 256 и 257 я буду знать, что они представляют собой `ab` и `ba`, но как их корректно прочесть?

[1]: [https://habr.com/ru/post/132683/#:~:text=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%20LZW,Jacob%20Ziv](https://habr.com/ru/post/132683/#:%7E:text=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%20LZW,Jacob%20Ziv))%20%D0%B2%201978%20%D0%B3.

Comment: Как определить, число 97 или 979?

Comment: @dIm0n да примерно в этом вопрос. Я пытаюсь реализовать разжатие по алгоритму LZW Так что первые два числа в файле гарантировано будут кодами символов ASCII, а новые слова будут будут начинаться с 256 кода, так что 979 в начале файла точно не будет

Comment: Ну так без дополнительной информации вы теоретически не можете этого узнать, независимо от того, как читать файл на цэ. Если алгоритм LZW как-то по-особенному записывает эти числа (например, числа только по 2 цифры, или 2 числа по 2 цифры + число в 3 цифры), то другое дело

Comment: Ну ок, 979 не может быть. А 1111 уже непонятно как делить

Comment: Вкратце про алгоритм https://habr.com/ru/post/132683/#:~:text=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%20LZW,Jacob%20Ziv)%20%D0%B2%201978%20%D0%B3.

Comment: Опишите в вопросе этот алгоритм, если считаете, что по нему можно однозначно восстановить последовательность

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, описать.

Comment: imho вам нужен не текстовый, а бинарный (двоичный) формат файла. Если у вас символы разного размера, то можно использовать кодировку [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). При этом 7-битные (ascii) символы останутся как есть и будут занимать один байт, числа от 128 до 2048 (11 бит) будут размещаться в 2-х байтах ... (дальше подсчитайте сами)

Comment: Если окажется, что большинство символов (чисел) в файле больше 2047, но меньше 0xffff, то можно просто использовать 2-х байтный short для каждого символа. В принципе, в процессе сжатия вы можете набирать такую статистику для каждого выходного блока разумного размера и записывать в начало блока признак того или иного формата

Comment: Впрочем, более разумно посмотреть на оригинальный [LZW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0) и реализовать функцию чтения чисел с разным размером бит из буфера.

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает писать int бинарно по 4 байта ну или по sizeof(int)?
Ну а потом читать по 4 байта как вы и писали

Вот пример

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int dump(int* arr, unsigned int size, char* file_name)
{
  if (!size || !arr)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen(file_name, "wb");
  if (!fptr)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file!\n");
    return 2;
    }
  fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr[0]),  size, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}

int FileExist(char *filename)
{
  struct stat st;
  int result = stat(filename, &st);
  if (result != 0)
  {
    printf("File not found %s\n", filename);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

long int GetFileSize(char* file_name)
{
  FILE *source;
  source=fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (source == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error take file size\n");
    return 1;
  }
  fseek(source, 0, SEEK_END);
  long int source_size = ftell(source);
  fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fclose(source);

  return source_size;
}

typedef struct _pview {
  void* _ptr;
  size_t _size;
} _pview;

_pview read(char *filename)
{
  _pview ret;
  ret._ptr = NULL;
  if (FileExist(filename))
  {
    return ret;
  }
  
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (!fptr)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file!\n");
    return ret;
    }

  long int size = GetFileSize(filename);
  size_t arr_size = (size_t)size / sizeof(int);
  

  ret._ptr = (int*)malloc((size_t)size);
  if (!ret._ptr)
  {
    return ret;
  }

  fread(ret._ptr, sizeof(int), arr_size, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
  ret._size = size;
  
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] ={10, 20, 123, 2134, 14};
  unsigned int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  int ret = dump(arr, arr_size, "dump.bin");
  if (ret)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
    return ret;
  }

  _pview data = read("dump.bin");
  if (!data._ptr)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < data._size / sizeof(int); ++i)
  {
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", ((int*)data._ptr)[i]);
  }

  if (data._ptr)
  {
    free(data._ptr);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуй, 4 байта расточительно для целей автора (сжатие файла)

Comment: @avp ну тогда надо городить структуры с хедерами и телом

Comment: @avp + автор писал - Возможно, читать из файла по 4 байта

Comment: [LZW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0). На самом деле ему нужно выбирать разное количество бит на число по ходу декодирования. В любом случае понадобится буфер из которого он будет их брать